# OpenSSH Server en Windows 10

Tags: ssh

He instalado OpenServer SSH en Windows 10 y estoy intentando conectarme desde un PC con Linux a a través del SSH con el PC con Windows 10. El nombre del usuario y el localhost los tengo claros, pero lo que no tengo claro es la clave que debo ingresar para poder acceder ya que estoy gastando el sistema PIN de Windows 10 y me dice que es errónea.

Comment: Revisa “RustDesk”.